# Why Inserting a value in a nullable field from a HTML FORM gives me a NULL even if it is not?

Tags: php, mysql

I created a database with a table that contains both mandatory and nullable fields. When I insert mandatory fields everyhing works fine, but when I try to insert a value in a field that is optional and can be NULL i always get a NULL result when checking the database.
Here's the code: (user_id is **mandatory** and username is **optional**. Whether I type something in *username* or not I always get a NULL in the corresponding db field.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Users</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Users input:</h1> <br/>
<FORM ID="users_input" NAME="users_input" METHOD="POST"
ACTION="get_users.php">
<LABEL>User_ID:
<INPUT TYPE="INT" NAME="user_id" ID="user_id"/>
</LABEL>
<LABEL>User name:
<INPUT TYPE="INT" NAME="username" ID="username"/>
</LABEL>
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="Submit" ID="Submit" Value="Submit" />
</FORM>
</body>
</html>

**get_users.php**

  <?php include "conn.php"; ?>
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['username']))
{
$username=$_POST['username'];
$query="INSERT INTO users (username)
VALUES('".$_POST["username"]."')";
mysql_query($query,$conn);}
else
{
$username=NULL;
}

if (!empty($_POST['user_id']))
{
$user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
$query="INSERT INTO users(user_id) VALUES('".$_POST["user_id"]."')";
mysql_query($query,$conn);

}
else
{ echo "error";

}

?>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you provide some example cases of `username` being filled and not being filled and the result you're getting?

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. A couple things. Input fields do not have a `type="int"` - if you want to enforce a number, you can `type="number"` - but you might not want numeric usernames. Also, no need to capitalize your HTML tags

Comment: 2 more things. Consider using `mysqli` rather than `mysql`. There are many reasons to do this, one of which is `mysql` is no longer supported and may go away in a future php release. AND, it's important to protect your database from attacks, so you really should start using prepared statements. It's just good (and necessary) practice: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: The (original) `mysql` extension is already not supported since PHP 7.0. Basically there is no officially supported PHP version that would still have it. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is performing two `INSERT` queries. eEach `INSERT` will create a new row, but the query that inserts only the `username` will fail because the `user_id` is set `NOT NULL`. Hence. you see one rwo with just the user ID and no user name.

You need to insert both fields in one `INSERT`, so, in the context you ask the question do this (but see below):

```
if (!empty($_POST['user_id']))
{
  $username = empty($_POST['username'])?null:$_POST['username'];
  $user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
  $query="INSERT INTO users(user_id,username) VALUES('$user_id','$username')";
  mysql_query($query,$conn) or die(mysql_error($conn));
}
else
{
 echo "error";
}
```

**Important**: The solution above is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/14853083). `mysql_*()` is also an archaic interface to MySQL - it was removed from PHP7 some years ago. You'd do better using [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) which also allows you to use prepared statements. The PDO version of this is:

```
<?php
/**
 * get_users.php
 *
 */

$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'dbname';
$dbuser = 'dbuser';
$dbpass = 'dbpass';

$conn = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$dbhost", $dbuser, $dbpass);
// Set PDO to throw an exception on error
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {
    if (!empty($_POST['user_id'])) {
        $username = empty($_POST['username']) ? null : $_POST['username'];
        $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];

        // Query with placeholders instead of values
        $query = "INSERT INTO users(user_id,username) VALUES(:userid,:username)";

        // Prepare query
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

        // Execute query with array of values to use in place of placeholders
        $stmt->execute([':userid' => $user_id, ':username' => $username]);

    } else {
        echo "error: no user ID";
    }
    echo 'User added successfully';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```